# Web Deploy does not include files necessary for NHibernate in deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am building my deployment process and I am running into a really annoying problem.

Using Visual Studio 2010 Sp1 on a .Net4 project with ASP.NET MVC3 that I want to deploy to an IIS7.5 webserver. The deployment works fine - both from Visual Studio and command line - except for this one important part:

I am using NHibernate (with Fluent NH) in a class library that is referenced by my web app. These were installed using NuGet, and also show up on the server when deployed.

However, these depend on some other libraries:

- Castle.Core
- Iesi.Collections
- NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle

These are also fetched by NuGet, they are referenced in my class library, and the references have "Copy Local" set to True. However, out of these three, only Iesi.Collections actually show up on the server!

Of course, I can copy them manually, but the next time I run the deploy, it will delete them. Deleting unused files is actually something I want, but these files should not be in that category!

What can I do to make Web Deploy respect the fact that these guys are desired members of my application!?

Comment: You need to include those into your web app for them to be included into the web deploy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding those assemblies as references to your web project otherwise implicit references in class libraries might not be included.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! It feels a little wrong to have to reference these libraries in the web project as it doesn't use them directly, but I guess the deployment stuff can't figure out the dependencies of the class library.. I still think this is strange, since it picks up Iesi.Collections but not the others.. Oh well, it works! Thanks!